# HDFS file on NFS always after 28 seconds

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I'm learning to use HDFS. I've downloaded, started it, added the very basic stuff to make the NFS gateway run[1], and it works, hooray!

Now, I've compiled [2], and it works! but after some testing, I've verified that the file appears on the gateway *always after 28 seconds*! Is that normal? Can I correct it? I mean, make the file appear faster, I don't know, after a couple of seconds max.? half a minute is a lot for my processes!

What am I missing? I dont' see any time setting on the configuration, this is the only stuff I've configured:

core-site.xml:

- hadoop.tmp.dir==/opt/hadoop/tmp,
- fs.default.name==hdfs://192.168.1.11:54310,
- hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups==*,
- hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts==*

hdfs-site.xml:

- dfs.namenode.name.dir==file:/opt/hadoop/hdfs/namenode
- dfs.datanode.data.dir==file:/opt/hadoop/hdfs/datanode

EDIT 20180801: following cricket_007's question, I've verified several times that a 1Gb file takes 21 seconds to appear on the NFS gateway; only once it took 20s.

[1] https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_hdfs-nfs-gateway-user-guide/content/user-guide-hdfs-nfs-instructions.html

[2] https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html

Comment: Does file size matter for the observed speed?

Comment: @cricket_007 good point: the example as is (13 bytes), takes 28 seconds, but a 1Gb file lasts 21 seconds (verified several times)! I'm a bit limited with this test machine resources, and hdfs starts complaining about heap space with 2Gb. Anyway, this seems quite weird...

Comment: Yeah, that's very limited heap. In any case, Hadoop prefers files larger than its block size (default 128Mb). That 13 bytes, while small, requires lots of left over space for the namenode to track. I'm guessing `hdfs dfs -put` from that machine doesn't take that long? Have you tried WebHDFS?